# Displaying and storing Windows Batch file output

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch-file, redirection

I've got a batch file written that runs a program we've developped, passing in a number of parameters. Whilst running the program in debug mode, a large number of debug messages are output, which it would be handy to review later, although I still want to be able to see the program running "live" as it were, within the cmd.exe window.

In a *nix environment I could use Tee to output to both the text file and stdout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TEE for Windows](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/tee.php)
TEE enables you to redirect standard output to a file and display it on screen simultaneously.

```
some_program | TEE [ /D:nn ] file_name
```

Available as BAT, Perl and Regina scripts.

Author's note.

> The Rexx and Perl scripts will start displaying the result immediately.
>   For the batch file, what it boils down to is, you may just as well redirect the command's output to a file and then display that file afterwards. As a bonus, that way you won't skip empty lines.
>
> **Note**:  These scripts were written just for fun.
>   Even though the do work, they cannot compete with the "real" stuff -- compiled executables, written in "true" programming languages by true programmers.

---

I use Cygwin.
There is also [**Tee utility for Windows updated**](http://www.chipstips.com/?p=349)

Comment: Unfortunately Cygwin's not an option here. Works a treat though, and the zip includes a compiled executable as well. Perfect!

Comment: The link to Tee utility for Windows updated is dead. Archive copy at https://www.chipstips.com/?p=349

Comment: There are many other solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tee.bat tool for this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
 SET Append=false 
IF /I "%~1]=="/a" ( SET Append=true & SHIFT )
IF "%~1"== "" GOTO help
IF "%~2"== "" GOTO help
 SET Counter=0 
FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /A /B %1 2^>NUL') DO CALL :Count "%%~fA"
 IF %Counter% GTR 1 ( SET Counter= & GOTO Syntax ) 
 SET File=%1
 DIR /AD %File% >NUL 2>NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ( SET File= & GOTO Syntax ) 
 SET Y= 
VER | FIND "Windows NT" > NUL 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET Y=/Y
 IF %Append%==false  (COPY %Y% NUL %File% > NUL 2>&1) 
 FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
    > CON ECHO.%%B  
        >> %File% ECHO.%%B
 ) 
ENDLOCAL 
GOTO:EOF
 :Count 
SET /A Counter += 1
 SET File=%1 
GOTO:EOF
 :help
 ECHO.
 ECHO Display text on screen and redirect it to a file simultaneously ECHO Usage: some_command ^| TEE.BAT [ /a ] filename 
 ECHO. 
ECHO Where: "some_command" is the command whose output should be redirected
 ECHO "filename" is the file the output should be redirected to
 ECHO /a appends the output of the command to the file,
 ECHO rather than overwriting the file
 ECHO. 
ECHO Made by Wasif Hasan.
```

> Usage: `command | tee [/a] filename`
>
> `/a` switch append input to file rather than overwriting it.

Comment: doesn't work if command need arguments, i.e. command arg1 arg2 | tee filename